# Changing just one of the dependencies in a large graph of dependencies in an ioc container for testing purposes

Tags: java, oop, unit-testing, testing, dependency-injection

This is my app's composition root:

```
    MutablePicoContainer container = new DefaultPicoContainer();
    container.addComponent(LDAPManager.class);
    container.addComponent(LoginDelayer.class);
    container.addComponent(CommandFactory.class);
    container.addComponent(FileSystem.class);
    container.addComponent(ProtocolFactory.class);
    container.addComponent(new TemporaryFolder(container.getComponent(FileSystem.class), new File("abc")));
    container.addComponent(ConnectedClientFactory.class);
    container.addComponent(Server.class);

    Server server = container.getComponent(Server.class);
```

This is cute and dandy, but there still a problem: when system-testing, I'll generally want to either mock or pass a different implementation of just one or two of those dependencies. It'd be ideal if I could just have the code shown above plus

```
container.addComponent(new TemporaryFolder(container.getComponent(FileSystem.class), new File("def")));
```

and have the container understand that I want to replace the initial `TemporaryFolder` instance with this new one. Is there any built-in facility for this in pico-container (or other Java lightweight containers)? If not, what's the standard approach to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It might be IoC framework specific but we do this in Windsor with .net for our Acceptance Testing. Each of our services wire up there own container with all the components that they need.

In our acceptance tests we inherit from out service and call it `TestXyzService` and in there override any of the components that need to be overridden but leave the rest alone. This way we are testing as much as we can without making things too hard on ourselves.

In our case we have to make sure that we register the mocked or dummy component before the real one is registered in the base class as the first component takes presidence in Windsor.

Comment: yet the question remains. how do you " and in there override any of the components that need to be overridden"?

Comment: @devouredelysium what happens if you register the same component twice? Just had a look at the api, looks like there is a couple of remove methods on the mutable container, are these not of any use?

Answer (score 1):

Based on Bronumski answer, I've made a simple hackclass that *seems* to be working for my purposes atm:

```
import org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer;
import org.picocontainer.MutablePicoContainer;
import org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.UnsatisfiableDependenciesException;

public class IoCContainer {
    private final MutablePicoContainer container = new DefaultPicoContainer();

    public void addComponent(Object component) {
        if (containsComponent(component.getClass()))
            container.removeComponent(component.getClass());

        container.addComponent(component.getClass(), component);
    }

    public void addComponent(Class<?> key, Object component) {
        if (containsComponent(key))
            container.removeComponent(key);

        container.addComponent(key, component);
    }

    public void addComponent(Class<?> key, Class<?> component) {
        if (containsComponent(key))
            container.removeComponent(key);

        container.addComponent(key, component);
    }

    public void addComponent(Class<?> component) {
        if (containsComponent(component))
            container.removeComponent(component);

        container.addComponent(component);
    }

    public boolean containsComponent(Class<?> component) {
        try {
            container.getComponent(component);
        } catch (UnsatisfiableDependenciesException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public <T> T getComponent(Class<T> component) {
        T result = container.getComponent(component);
        if (result == null)
            throw new NoComponentFoundException();

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is very easy. Note this caveat from the Javadoc for [`addComponent(java.lang.Object)`](http://picocontainer.org/javadoc/core/org/picocontainer/DefaultPicoContainer.html#addComponent(java.lang.Object))

> Register an arbitrary object. **The class of the object will be used as
>   a key.** Calling this method is equivalent to calling
>   `addComponent(componentImplementation, componentImplementation)`.

(Emphasis mine.)

You can also set the key explicitly by using [`addComponent(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, org.picocontainer.Parameter...)`](http://picocontainer.org/javadoc/core/org/picocontainer/DefaultPicoContainer.html#addComponent%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object,%20org.picocontainer.Parameter...%29), if you desire.

Based upon additional information, this behavior will cause a key collision when two members of the same class are specified to the former interface. To fix this, you'll need some method to reconcile the conflict... which you've gone ahead and [provided a working code example for here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9856415/517815).

I openly admit that I don't use this framework for dependency injection, so if I'm off-base here, my apologies. I do highly recommend giving [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) a try sometime, though. It's an absolute pleasure to use for these scenarios.

Comment: "Have you tried using comparable class types to see if this just works?". Yes, I have (take a look at the other post). It will crash at run-time. I fail to understand how mockito would be of any help here.

Comment: @devouredelysium No worries. You already have the right idea and the correct solution. It's very clear that the dependency injector rejects key collisions, such that the correct resolution is to first remove then re-inject a member for that candidate key. It's unintuitive (based on the documentation), but it will work. I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @devouredelysium As for Mockito: it isn't currently applicable, but I've learned to rely on its explicit DI model for a large number of unit tests. It won't solve this problem in the context of your extant code, but it's a simple mock/DI framework to consider. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of the [disambiguation techniques](http://picocontainer.org/disambiguation.html) to make you test component more specific than your normal real component, so that your test one overrides it. 
e.g.

```
public class Service {
    private String data;

    public Service(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MutablePicoContainer container = new DefaultPicoContainer();
        container.as(Characteristics.USE_NAMES).addComponent(Service.class);
        container.addComponent("Real Data");
        // below line added only in test for injecting test data ...
        container.addComponent("data", "Mock Data"); 
        System.out.println(container.getComponent(Service.class).getData());
    }
}
```

and this prints `Mock Data` if the "Mock Data" line is present, and `Real Data` if its commented out. This works because 'data' is the parameter name.